# How can I convert a point in EPSG:25832 to display it in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, proj4js

Say I have the following point in EPSG:25832:
[[799325.792813, 5828257.530253]](https://epsg.io/map#srs=3857&x=1493102.706342&y=6895070.810356&z=20&layer=streets)

I am having trouble displaying it on a leaflet map.

Using proj4, I was able to convert it to EPSG:3857

```js
import proj4 from 'proj4'
import {transform} from 'ol/proj'
import {register} from 'ol/proj/proj4'

proj4.defs('EPSG:25832', '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')

register(proj4)
transform([799325.792813, 5828257.530253], 'EPSG:25832', 'EPSG:3857')
// result: [1493102.7063423465, 6895070.810356369]
```

So the result is again in meters. I have tried to unproject the result to get the coordinates in degrees:

```js
leafletObject?.unproject([1493102.7063423465, 6895070.810356369])
// result: {lat: -90, lng: 32627.43251240508}
```

But that does not yield the right result.

I then tried directly transforming to WGS84 in proj4, but the result is off the coast of northern France rather than in Berlin:

```js
const [lat, lng] = transform([799325.792813, 5828257.530253], 'EPSG:25832', 'WGS84')
//result: [51.01550382751145, 1.9889839639171145]
leafletObject?.addLayer(L.marker({lat, lng}))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this - I was actually almost there but in my actual code I was passing the x/y values in the wrong order. The following actually works:

```js
import proj4 from 'proj4'
import {transform} from 'ol/proj'
import {register} from 'ol/proj/proj4'

proj4.defs('EPSG:25832', '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')

register(proj4)

const [lng, lat] = transform([799325.792813, 5828257.530253], props.projection, 'WGS84')
// result: [13.412769818675514, 52.522027929194834]

leafletObject?.addLayer(L.marker({lat, lng}))
```